# Expand and collapse a canvas with a sliding effect - UWP C#

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a grid. which contains a canvas of textblock and an image below it. I want to hide the canvas when user clicks on grid. And if he clicks again on it I want to show the canvas again and vice versa. This expansion and collapse should happens in an animated/sliding way. Which means I want to get an Expander to animate opening and closing with a "slide" action. How can I achieve this?

```
<Grid x:Name="NotiifcationGrid"  Background="#002F43" Height="50" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Canvas Grid.Row="0">
                <Canvas.Clip>
                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="0, 0, 1700, 100" />
                </Canvas.Clip>
                <TextBlock Name="txtScrollingNotification" Foreground="White" 
                   Text="This textblock is getting marquee effect." />
            </Canvas>
            <Image x:Name="img_greenline" Grid.Row="1"  Height="40" Width="80"  Source="Assets/green_line.png"  />
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
                    <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="txtScrollingNotification"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                Duration="0:0:20" From="1700"
                To="-500"  
                RepeatBehavior="Forever"  />
                </Storyboard>
            </Grid.Resources>
        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to animate adding and deleting of content in your `Grid`, then you should use [`AddDeleteThemeTransition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.adddeletethemetransition).

Like this:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ChildrenTransition>
     <AddDeleteThemeTransition/>
  </Grid.ChildrenTransition>
  <Canvas..../>
  <Image...../>
</Grid>
```

Also, If you  don't like the output and your problem specially need  the Expander solution, then you can use the [Expander in Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.controls.expander).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get it. Not adding and deleting of content .It is just showing and hiding . When hide the canvas it should disappear in a sliding manner

Answer (score 0):

> I want to hide the canvas when user clicks on grid. And if he clicks again on it I want to show the canvas again and vice versa. This expansion and collapse should happens in an animated/sliding way.

I've checked your XAML code, using `Storyboard` was a good choice, but you need to add another storyboard to achieve your target.

I've made a code sample for your reference. Please check the following code sample:

```
<Grid x:Name="NotiifcationGrid"  Background="#002F43" Height="50" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Tapped="NotiifcationGrid_Tapped">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Canvas Grid.Row="0" x:Name="canvas">
            <Canvas.Clip>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0, 0, 1700, 100" />
            </Canvas.Clip>
            <TextBlock Name="txtScrollingNotification" Foreground="White" 
               Text="This textblock is getting marquee effect."/>
        </Canvas>
        <Image x:Name="img_greenline" Grid.Row="1"  Height="40" Width="80"  Source="Assets/green_line.png"  />
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1" Completed="Storyboard1_Completed">
                <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="txtScrollingNotification"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
            Duration="0:0:2" From="0"
            To="-500"  
            />
            </Storyboard>

            <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard2">
                <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="txtScrollingNotification"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
            Duration="0:0:2" From="-500"
            To="0"  
            />
            </Storyboard>
        </Grid.Resources>
</Grid>
```

```cs
private void NotiifcationGrid_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (canvas.Visibility == Visibility)
        {
            Storyboard1.Begin();
        }
        else
        {
            canvas.Visibility = Visibility;
            Storyboard2.Begin();
        }
    }

    private void Storyboard1_Completed(object sender, object e)
    {
        canvas.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

***[Updated on 2018/9/3]***

> sorry this is not what i meant. that canvas shows some notifications. so when user touch on that NotiifcationGrid , he should feel like it is hiding. and again if he touch on it he should able to see those notification row. Now what happens is only that notification text is hiding. I want to hide that entire row Grid.Row="0" (should feel like hide from bottom to top in a slow motion)

If so, you do not need to make such a notification control in your app UI by yourself. The [UWP communitytoolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit) has an existing [InAppNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/inappnotification) control. You could use it in your app directly.

Comment: sorry this is not what i meant. that canvas shows some notifications. so when user touch on that NotiifcationGrid , he should feel like it is hiding. and again if he touch on it he should able to see those notification row. Now what happens is only that notification text is hiding. I want to hide that entire row  Grid.Row="0"  (should feel like hide from bottom to top in a slow motion)

Comment: no other way with storyboard? like hiding a grid row in animated way ?

Comment: There's no property for you to set the grid row's visibility. With my understanding, what you mean about 'hiding grid row' equivalents to hidden the content in this row. You could remove the row by `NotiifcationGrid.RowDefinitions.RemoveAt(0)`, but you will still see the canvas on the UI, you still need to hide or remove the canvas. So, why not use the `InAppNotification` control directly. It has helped you achieve all effect, inculding animation.